# Python: How is the dictionary stored in the memory

Tags: python, dictionary

I created a dictionary as follows -

```
accounts = {'ICICI':4567898765456,\
    'Citi':89889787868987,\
    'Chase':5678765434567}
```

And it gave the following result

```
accounts
{'Citi': 89889787868987L, 'ICICI': 4567898765456L, 'Chase': 5678765434567L}
```

Well I have observed that the dictionary usually does not store the dictionary in the same order as you declare it when the key is a String.

Is it something to do with how dictionaries are stored in the memory. If so, can someone please illustrate. Is there a way to enforce the order of dictionary as I declare them.

Comment: `collections.OrderedDict`

Comment: Documentation for OrderedDict -> https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Comment: Thanks.. the hash method of finding the order was really helpful. This can be closed. I don't know how to close this.